# lotusscript:How to add two or more email id to the Recipients

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

I have already the lotusscript code which is working correctly But now i have to add one more email id in the Recipient for the below code

Current Code:

```
Call currdoc.Save(True, False)
Set maildoc2 = New NotesDocument(maildb)
maildoc2.Form = "Menu"
maildoc2.Type = "Color Code"
maildoc2.SendTo = "lotwor@col.com"
maildoc2.Recipients = "lotwor@col.com"
maildoc2.From = "FRIENDS/COLOR"
maildoc2.Body = "This automated email message"
```

I tried to add one more email id as `lotusrt@cot.com` using two ways and it is still not working.

```
 first way:

Call currdoc.Save(True, False)
    Set maildoc2 = New NotesDocument(maildb)
    maildoc2.Form = "Menu"
    maildoc2.Type = "Color Code"
    maildoc2.SendTo = "lotwor@col.com",lotusrt@cot.com
    maildoc2.Recipients = "lotwor@col.com",lotusrt@cot.com
    maildoc2.From = "FRIENDS/COLOR"
    maildoc2.Body = "This automated email message"
```

Second Way is like this by creating address code.

```
Dim addressesss (1 To 2) As String
    addressesss(1) = "lotwor@col.com",
    addressesss(2) = "lotusrt@cot.com"

    Set maildoc2 = New NotesDocument(maildb)
    maildoc2.Form = "Menu"
    maildoc2.Type = "Color Code"
    maildoc2.SendTo = addressesss
    maildoc2.Recipients = addressesss
    maildoc2.From = "FRIENDS/COLOR"
    maildoc2.Body = "This automated email message"
```

So can anyone tell me what correction need to done for above code such that the emails will be sent to both the email ids and thanks for your help and time.

Now currently the emails are not sending it to the particular recipients.

Comment: Is the comma in `addressesss(1) = "lotwor@col.com",` really in your code?

Comment: @TorstenLink No the comma is not in my Code

Comment: @TorstenLink while adding the question i mistakely added it

Comment: There is no need to set the value of Recipients. Just set the value of SendTo. The will set the Recipients item for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way is correct, but perhaps you have a typo in your second email address?

```
Dim addresses (1 To 2) As String
addresses(1) = "lotwor@col.com",
addresses(2) = "lotusrt@col.com"

Set maildoc2 = New NotesDocument(maildb)
maildoc2.Form = "Menu"
maildoc2.Type = "Color Code"
maildoc2.SendTo = addresses
maildoc2.Recipients = addresses
maildoc2.From = "FRIENDS/COLOR"
maildoc2.Body = "This automated email message"
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? No mail sent at all? Mail sent only to one recipient? Error message?

Comment: I've never seen the syntax "Dim addresses (1 to 2)" before.  As far as I know, if you want an array with only (1) and (2), you "Option Base 1" and then "Dim addresses (2)", or just leave at base 0, Dim Addresses(1) and use (0) and (1).  The Dim statement sets the UBound for the array.

Comment: @Duston: it is the definition of `(lowerBound To upperBound)` - look here for more information: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_ARRAYS.html